Вызов метода из другого метода (не только из Main)
Существует метод "Line" Выводящий в консоль строчку из 100 символов '/'
При запуске через "Main" при помощиLine(args); работает как надо, но при запуске из другого метода "Result", который помимо этого выводит некоторое сообщение в консоль, выводит ошибку
"Имя "args" не существует в текущем контексте."
Вообще я не знаю что такое этот ваш args (типо аргументы или что-то в этом роде), но главное работает, объясните пожалуйста новичку что делать.
Весь код выглядит так:
private static void Line (String[] args)
{
    string writing = new string ('/', 100);
    Console.WriteLine(writing);
}
private static void Result (double c)
{
    Line(args);
    Console.WriteLine(c);
}

Вывод должен быть примерно таким:
//////////////////////////////////////////////////.......
*значение переменной c*


уберите этот args из вашей функции, вы ж его не используете всё равно

Вообще я не знаю что такое этот ваш args - а зачем ты тогда его добавил в свою функцию?
